# number of expected time bins when performing stft with scipy.signal.stft()

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

I am using `scipy.signal.stft()` to compute the spectrogram for a set of samples with sampling frequency of 2.048 MHz, with 2^18 samples, `fft` size of 128 and overlap of 75%, with hamming window. Therefore the expected number of time bins would be:

```
numbins = (numsamples - windowsize)/hope_size = (2^18-128)/32 = 8188
```

but `scipy.signal.stft()` outputs 8193 time bins.

I have tried other overlaps, `fftsizes` playing with the boundary argument but noting worked. Does someone know why I am not getting the expected number of time bins? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: play with `padded` and `boundary` arguments of the `stft` function